# How to center search bar in navbar-bottom and prevent it from resizing when window is resized to be smaller?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a search bar on the footer using Bootstrap. The search bar appears to display properly when the window is maximized. However, when I try to resize the window to be smaller, the search form widens and the height of the bottom navbar appears to increase, as shown in the picture below:

[image]

What I want is for the navbar height to stay the same. The search bar should also not expand in length. Basically, even with a smaller window, the navbar should appear as follows:

[image]

The HTML code that I used to generate the bottom navbar is provided below:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
<div class="container">
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gpsForm" placeholder="Latitude, Longitude">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Search
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm fairly new to Bootstrap and web development in general and I've been stuck trying to look for a solution to this problem for several hours without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
<div class="container">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="gpsForm" placeholder="Latitude, Longitude">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Search
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9093/

Now you can add styling like padding and margin as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove **"navbar-form"** class from your form and try again.

Instead of this

```
form class="navbar-form navbar-left"
```

Try as

```
form class="navbar-left"
```

Comment: I gave this solution a try and all it does is expand the search input field to the entire width of the bottom navbar. Additionally, the navbar still resizes in height when the window is resized to be smaller.